# Service Fabric node in error state

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I just checked on my Service Fabric cluster in the Azure portal and i noticed that one of the nodes is in error state, with the following error:

`Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='FabricUpgrade:5.5.216.0:3'.
Fabric upgrade failed on the node.`

What is the best course of action to fix the node?

Comment: Didn't you get an email from MS with the reason and remedial actions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade

Comment: I don't own the account that the cluster is in, so I did not get the email...

Answer (score 1):

Doing an OS reboot of the affected node seemed to bring everything back to green.  We are working with MS Azure support to figure out why the upgrade failed in the first place.

Comment: Does system event log on errored node give more detail?

Comment: We ended out finding that the MSI on the node was corrupt.  Restarting the update worked fine.

Comment: It helped me.. I have restarted from powershell by `Restart-ServiceFabricNode -NodeName "NODENAME" -CommandCompletionMode DoNotVerify`

Answer (score 0):

Did you replace the MSI and restart?  I am getting this error on a node.

I am running on-premise

Comment: The Azure Support representative had me clear out the MSI from a few locations, and then had me run the upgrade manually.